# Can I disable the UIPageViewController's page border gesture recognizers? And keep the swipe one?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I see that I can remove all of the UIPageViewController gestures, but what if I only want to remove the tap gesture on the edges? And keep the swipe gesture? Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try looping through `pageViewController.gestureRecognizers`, disabling any that are tap recognizers.

Objective-C:

```objc
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in pageViewController.gestureRecognizers) {
    if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        recognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Swift:

```swift
for recognizer in pageViewController.gestureRecognizers {
    if recognizer is UITapGestureRecognizer {
        recognizer.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, this only works with UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl.

Comment: It worked for me on iOS 6 with both UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl and UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this in Swift:

```
    for recognizer in pageViewController.gestureRecognizers as! [UIGestureRecognizer] {
        if recognizer is UITapGestureRecognizer {
            recognizer.enabled = false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 4.2
add to viewDidLoad()

```
for recognizer in self.gestureRecognizers {
            if recognizer is UITapGestureRecognizer {
                recognizer.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
```